# Stata odbc get column comment as label

Tags: sql, stata, impala

I am trying to access data from impala sql into Stata:

```
clear all
#delimit;
odbc load, exec("
SELECT column_name
data_base_name.table_name
")
dsn("<my dsn>")
user("")
password("");
#delimit cr
```

The query works just fine, but the labels are empty. Is there any way to get those into stata?

I created comments the following way:

```
ALTER TABLE  data_base_name.table_name
CHANGE column_name column_name string comment 'test comment';
```

So when I import to Stata the variable name `column_name` should have the label "test comment". Is this possible? Or any other way (other than comment I mean)?

Answer (score 4):

`help odbc` doesn't mention anything about comments, `odbc describe` doesn't return column comments and there is no mention in the manual about accessing comments, so there doesn't seem to be a straightforward way. Here's a workaround, using `moremata` from SSC.

```
odbc load, exec("DESCRIBE data_base_name.table_name") dsn("my dsn") clear
list

// Get variable names and comment labels
* ssc install moremata
mata: st_local("vars", invtokens(st_sdata(., ("name"))'))
mata: st_local("labels", mm_invtokens(st_sdata(., ("comment"))'))
local n_vars = _N

// Get actual data and label the variables
odbc load, exec("SELECT * FROM data_base_name.table_name") dsn("my dsn") clear
forval i = 1/`n_vars' {
    cap confirm variable `:word `i' of `vars''
    if !_rc label var `:word `i' of `vars'' "`:word `i' of `labels''"
}
```